# How to show the exact difference of words in WinMerge?

Tags: winmerge, difftool

Can I setup WinMerge so that it shows me the exact difference of single words?

Up to now the whole word/phrase is highlighted, even if only one character is different (see picture for an example).

The URL in line 11 is highlighted completely, even though only one character ("`http`" vs "`https`") is different
[image: Example Diff]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can indeed.

Open `WinMerge`, then under the `Edit` menu, choose `Options`:

[image: Edit Menu]

This will open the `Options (Editor)` window, from here, select the `Editor` sub-option. In here there will be a section labeled `Line Difference Coloring` where you can select how the differences will be highlighted. To do what you're wanting, make sure to check the box `View line differences` and select the option for `Character level`:

[image: Options Editor]

This will highlight the characters that are different on each line.

[image: diff]

Hope that can help.